# How to use Git Tokens in Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use Jenkinsfile to clone git branches and merge them.
Skeleton code is as below:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        label ""
    }
    stages {
        stage("Git") {
            steps {
                git( url: , credentialsId: )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime I run this I get the error

stderr: remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.

Does anyone know how to use git tokens from within jenkinsfile? I'd very much appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a GitHub access token, you must use standard Username with password credentials, where the username is the same as your GitHub username and the password is your access token.

Source - [Jenkins Pipeline as code](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline-as-code/)

Steps on how to create a personal access token - [Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

You should configure your `personal access token` or `SSH key`. Example for SSH key: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Then go to Jenkins > Credential > add a new credential. It's some kind of `SSH Username with private key` and the content is your SSH private key. Note the ID of the created credential.

Now you can fill your code above with `credentialsId: <id-goes-here>`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "GITHUB_TOKEN", variable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN')]) {
    // An example for getting the statuses for a commit using GITHUB_TOKEN:
    // Use env.GITHUB_TOKEN here or just let shell expand it...
    def statusJson = sh returnStdout: true, 
         script: "curl --fail -s -X GET -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' -u " +
          ":\$GITHUB_TOKEN " +
 "https://api.github.com/repos/myowner/myrepo/commits/$gitCommit/statuses"    

  }
```